# Encrypted bitcoin private key from bitcoin-cli

Tags: bitcoind, client, bitcoin-cli

Hi I need to know the command which is used to generate encrypted bitcoin private key from bitcoin-cli (for a bitcoin address) so in future when that private key is used for import address in any application it ask for password also ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such way to do that. Bitcoin Core does not support BIP 38 for private key encryption so you cannot export nor import an encrypted private key.

Comment: So how bitcoin Wallet available in market achieve this type of functionality as when I try to import my private key it ask for password ?

Comment: Those wallets implement the BIP 38 standard for private key encryption. Bitcoin Core does not. BIP 38 is not a consensus rule, just a wallet implementation thing, so wallets can choose to use it or not.